# How to move placeholder text few pixels to the right in select?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I've been stuck on this for couple of hours trying to:

1. Move placeholder text (Search) 10 pixels to the right in my select component and
2. decrease the height of the field (maybe 5px less) but no luck so far.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? thanks a lot in advance! here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjy4y5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
  <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableOptionCentering
    panelClass="my-mat-select-container">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
  {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to overwrite angular material style classes to achieve custom styling.

I have done a bit here, please put below css classes in styles.scss and see if you get what you are expecting. 
Feel free to play with the pixels to adjust labels.

```
// dropdown label 
.mat-form-field-label {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

// dropdown label 
.mat-form-field-flex {
  padding-top: 6px!important;
}

// dropdown label 
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding-bottom: 6px!important;
}

// dropdown options style
.mat-select-panel .mat-optgroup-label, .mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    height: 38px!important;
}

// dropdown options style
.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    padding-left: 25px !important;
}

// selected value text style
.mat-select-value-text {
   padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Note: To avoid using import you will have to give more explicit CSS handles.
e.g. For below code

```
<custom-directive>
   <mat-label >Select</mat-label>
</custom-directive>
```

, you should write css directive as :

```
custom-directive mat-label {
  // css here
}
```

You can use inspect element feature of chrome to know correct CSS handlers, below is the example image.
[image: Image to detect CSS handles]

Stackblitz code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjy4y5-r8urqh?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: Can you please provide a live demo solution? thanks

Comment: Here it is : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjy4y5-r8urqh?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: I don't think. your code is changing the height? I want to decrease the height too

Answer (score 1):

You can move the placeholder text by adding padding like below

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label-wrapper label mat-label {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

and for the height try

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-form-field-wrapper .mat-form-field-flex {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the padding-left on the placeholder, that works great! but the height solution doesn't work properly, if you set the height to 20px it looks like the background color changes but not the field

Comment: yes you will have to write some css for the rest of it.. you can follow the above examples and logic though

Comment: voting your answer up. Thanks bro!